# JSON Object with nameless elements

Tags: java, android, json

How can I parse a JSON like this, it comes as an object and has nameless strings in it.

```
{"2":"Rock","1":"Pop"}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonFile.length(); i++) {                   
                JSONArray jArr = jsonFile.getJSONArray("");                 
    }
```

Comment: it is a JSONObject not a JSONArray

Comment: Alright how do I parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). You shouldn't really be parsing JSON yourself. This is an extremely solved problem.

Use GSON for ease of use and quick startup, use Jackson if you want configuration options and performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper Class and conver it into hashmap and then itereate the map by getting keyset ..... like this

HashMap responseMap = new 
ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString ,HashMap.class);

```
for (String key : responseMap.keySet())
{
     System.out.println(responseMap.get(key));
}
```